# Can we get a sandbox please?

Tags: feature-request, api, testing

I think that we should have some sort of a sandbox site where we can post questions, answers and comments in a controlled environment.

Currently I'm working with Stack Overflow but I can't post "test data" over there because I cherish my neglected reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sandbox that @George Edison was referring to was formating sandbox.
I started a new API sandbox at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox should be free to post any test answers and comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3122/

Answer (score 0):

Due to the removal and clean-up of the meta sandbox, I would suggest that we make this question a "free for all" sandbox.

I was using the meta sandbox to simulate new answers and comments, but the original intent was only for markdown formatting it seems.