# Allow registrant to use write access without linking Stack Apps post

Tags: feature-request, write-access

Especially in light of the [Flatiron School](http://flatironschool.com/) [using the Stack Exchange API](https://twitter.com/tmslft/status/445992625670479872)* as a part of a student-created program, it'd be useful if you could use write methods without [the required Stack Apps post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) so long as the authentication token passed corresponded to the user who owns the API key registration.

This would let people use their own accounts to develop an application using write privileges without having to throw up an [app](/questions/tagged/app) "(Placeholder)" post, only requiring them to create a listing once the application was ready for other people to use.

<sub>*I don't know the full scope of this, but based on the several placeholder posts so far it seems to require write access</sub>

Comment: Related: (1) [Original feature request (now edited)](http://stackapps.com/q/4602/7653), and (2) [Error message and placeholder workaround](http://stackapps.com/q/4573/7653), and (3) [Ancient sandbox request/workaround (but still needs a placeholder post with API 2.2)](http://stackapps.com/q/364/7653).

Comment: Only justification I can see is possible (future) auditing?  IE, I see/install *Super_Evil_App* and can then trace it by ID (somehow? some day?) to a Stack Apps post and Stack Apps user?

Comment: The association is already tracked internally, so that's mostly only a concern for users of the application to have a place to complain. Assuming we still require a post for anyone who is not the API key owner to use the key, I think we'd end up with the best of both worlds (i.e. no app posts until the app is ready for others to use)

Comment: The only possible downside would be making sure this requirement was made clear, otherwise people might publish an app without creating the post and then no one could use it.