# Do the questions tagged "placeholder" need it explicitly in the title?

Tags: support, discussion, meta

I have create a placeholder question, but just noticed that all the other ones have "(placeholder)", "[PLACEHOLDER]" or some variant in the title.

Do I need to include it in the title if it's tagged?

Comment: [Brock Adams said so...](http://stackapps.com/a/4574/26088) although in *my* opinion, no - what's the point of the tag existing then?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, Title practice came first. Tag was added later.  Use of both is debatable (See answer and comments below).  IMO, use both. But if you use only one, it should be the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real expectation set for this, feel free to pick whichever option seems better to you.

I personally feel the tag is sufficient, but I could see how having it in the title might save some people some disappointment. My hope is that people will just finish their app and it won't matter much either way, so I'm not particularly concerned.

Comment: IIRC, The title verbiage was the custom for a few weeks before the tag was created.  [Tags in titles are officially frowned on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), but *placeholder* (IE, **"currently unusable"**) is such a crucial aspect of a post that [a useful title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) practically requires it. :)

Comment: Yeah, we just [need a better system](http://stackapps.com/questions/4608/allow-registrant-to-use-write-access-without-linking-stack-apps-post) anyway, because the way it works now is silly. :(